# Query Search Box to locate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

HELP! I have spent a day trying to figure this one out.

```js
// search function
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bc").hide();
    $("#exerciseSearch").keyup(function(){
 
        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

 
        // Loop through the comment list
        $("#exercisesCont div").each(function(){
 
            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();

 
            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });
 
        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
    });

});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control text-input" id="exerciseSearch" value="">
<div id='exercisesCont'>
  <div id='1'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>Turning this div to display:none</div>
  </div>
  <div id='2'>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>Turning this div to display:none</div>
  </div>    
  <div id='3'>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>Turning this div to display:none</div>
  </div>
  <div id='4'>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>Turning this div to display:none</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently when I search for '1' with my search function I am getting the result of '1'. This sounds great, however, it is for the 'text' in the child element of div 1.

What I need is to search for the Div ID (inside div id 'exerciseCont') instead of searching for 'text' and display that div and all its child elements (currently sibling elements are being turned to display:none).

I hope that makes sense? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#exercisesCont > div").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).children().eq(0).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();


        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
        }
    });
```